# Hadoop-1.2.1 in Solaris 11.1 VM: Call to name-node failed on connection exception

Tags: hadoop

Hi I am following this below guide in link for VirtualBox Solaris Zones Hadoop installation.

[Oracle Solaris Zones Hadoop Setup](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/hands-on-labs/hol-setup-hadoop-solaris-2041770.html#10)

I was able to successfully follow till step 10. Once I tried to check report I am getting this error::

---

adoop@name-node:~$ hadoop dfsadmin -report

---

14/05/17 16:45:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: name-node/192.168.1.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

14/05/17 16:45:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: name-node/192.168.1.1:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

....

14/05/17 16:45:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: name-node/192.168.1.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s);

retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

report: Call to name-node/192.168.1.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

hadoop@name-node:~$

---

can someone kindly suggest resolution.

Also netstat shows this
name-node.8021                          *.*                             0      0 128000      0 LISTEN
      *.50030                           *.*                             0      0 128000      0 LISTEN

how to configure dfsadmin to port 8021 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step to configure Hadoop cluster on Oracle Solaris 11.1 using zones --- http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2014/05/multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-oracle.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is too old question and you might have already solved it. But just in case if anyone is wondering.

in core-site.xml make the following changes

```
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://192.168.1.1:8021/</value>
</property>
```

This will configure name node server port.